# How to page more than 10,000 data with Laravel and Elastic-Search?

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'body'  => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
                'testField' => 'abc'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
$response = $client->search($params);
```

[How to page more than 10,000 data with Laravel and Elastic-Search ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAJM2.jpg)```

How can I paginate the data like this?

Answer (score 0):

For pagination you can use the following methods:

1. from-size
2. search after

You can add the 'from' and 'size' parameters to the $params array like this:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'body'  => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
                'testField' => 'abc'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'from' => 0,
    'size' => 10
];
$response = $client->search($params);
```

> The 'from' parameter determines the starting point for the results,
> and the 'size' parameter determines the number of results to return.
> In this example, the query will return the first 10 results starting
> from the first one (0-based index).

References: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html